# Inactive previous and first page link when I use PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing on pagedlist control

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pagedlist

Pagedlist paging control in my mvc application shows an inactive link of previous and first page when I use `PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing` for ajaxifying the control. If I don't use `PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing`, it is working fine but I want to implement ajax. any suggestion will be appreciated. Please let me know if you need more information or my question is not clear enough. I have looked [here](http://github.com/troygoode/PagedList/issues/50), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17336165/ajax-pagination-in-pagedlist-mvc-using-partial-page) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20694219/nuget-mvc-pagedlist-page-links-not-working-correctly).

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Paging", new
       {
           page,
           SDate = Request.QueryString["StartDate"],
           EDate = Request.QueryString["EndDate"],
           PNumber = Request.QueryString["ProjectNumber"],
           SkuID = Request.QueryString["SkuID"]
       }), PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing(new PagedListRenderOptions()
       { DisplayLinkToPreviousPage = PagedListDisplayMode.IfNeeded}
                             , new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "results" }))
```

Answer (score 2):

After struggling a day on such a trivial issue I found the way around it. I need to include Pagedlist control in my partial view rather then in Index view. I am answering because it might help someone else who get into the same situation.